# Actual/Current Value of a DoubleAnimation in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, storyboard

I'd like to get the Actual Value of an Animated property in Silverlight 4.0

I'd like to animate a ScaleTransform ScaleX Property and need the actual Value when i stop the Storyboard.

I also tryed this: http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2010/09/siliverlight-on-windows-phone-7-get.html but it did not work!

Comment: Stopping a storyboard resets the value to what it was before it started.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the currennt Rotation property of a RenderTransform with the following

```
var x = needle.RenderTransform.GetValue(CompositeTransform.RotationProperty);
```

so I guess you just replace `RotationProperty` with `ScaleXProperty`

where needle =

```
   <ed:RegularPolygon Name="needle" Height="81.5" InnerRadius="1" Canvas.Left="78" PointCount="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="17.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="15" Fill="#FFFFBB00" StrokeThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.838" >
            <ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-140"/>
            </ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
        </ed:RegularPolygon>
```